# Converting existence of any text in a pandas column to a number value

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to find this specific question but hopefully it's an easy one. I have a pandas dataframe with a column with mixed numbers and text. I just want to convert any text instances in that column to the value 999. e.g. for column B, I'd like to perform this operation on, so:

```
A  B
1  1
2  5
3  FDS
4  EWR
5  7
6  3
7  BB
8  C
```

becomes...

```
A  B
1  1
2  5
3  999
4  999
5  7
6  3
7  999
8  999
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) clause + [`Series.str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html):

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['B'].str.isnumeric(), df['B'], 999).astype(int)
```

---

```
   A    B
0  1    1
1  2    5
2  3  999
3  4  999
4  5    7
5  6    3
6  7  999
7  8  999
```

Comment: Thank you. As with most of my requests, usually ends up being glaringly obvious !

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
df['B'] = pd.to_numeric(df['B'], errors='coerce').fillna(999).astype(int)
```

`df` after:

```
   A    B
0  1    1
1  2    5
2  3  999
3  4  999
4  5    7
5  6    3
6  7  999
7  8  999
```